# access files outside the folder in the same directory in python

Tags: python, directory

I have a folder structure build like this,

```
MainFolder
  -SubFolder1
  -SubFolder2
  -SubFolder3
     -File1.py
     -File2.py
  -SubFile.py
  -SubFile1.py
```

Now I want to import SubFile.py from File1.py.Also, SubFile.py has imported SubFile1.py in its code. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative imports

```py
from .. import subFile
```

if you're using python>=2.5